# How to remove review summary field in product review form in magento 2

Tags: frontend, magento2.2, form-validation, product-review

I need to remove review summary field in product review form.I have modified the core review form in my custom form. But Now, I need to remove validation for review summary field in Product review form. Please provide me a solution

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have solved the issue using overriding ( preference)